# Input Auto-complete doesn't work with label & value

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

i use below code to input auto-complete, Since i have multiple value so i added `label` to display but after adding `label` my auto-complete function doesn't do anything.

Can some one help me solve to this issue.

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
                var currentFocus;
                inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
                    var a, b, i, val = this.value;
                    closeAllLists();
                    if (!val) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    currentFocus = -1;
                    a = document.createElement("DIV");
                    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
                    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase()) {
                            b = document.createElement("DIV");
                            b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                            b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                            b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                            b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                                inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                                closeAllLists();
                            });
                            a.appendChild(b);
                        }
                    }
                });
                inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
                    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                    if (x)
                        x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
                    if (e.keyCode === 40) {
                        currentFocus++;
                        addActive(x);
                    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
                        currentFocus--;
                        addActive(x);
                    } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (currentFocus > -1) {
                            if (x)
                                x[currentFocus].click();
                        }
                    }
                });
                function addActive(x) {
                    if (!x)
                        return false;
                    removeActive(x);
                    if (currentFocus >= x.length)
                        currentFocus = 0;
                    if (currentFocus < 0)
                        currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
                    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
                }
                function removeActive(x) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
                    }
                }
                function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
                    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        if (elmnt !== x[i] && elmnt !== inp) {
                            x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    closeAllLists(e.target);
                });
            }
            var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia"];
            autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```html
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
 <input type="hidden" name="Country">
            </div>
```

So to make `label` i done this and it doesn't work

i changed

```
var countries = [{
                    "value": "Afghanistan, Pakistan",
                    "label": "Afghanistan"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Albania, Balkans",
                    "label": "Albania"
                }];
```

**Note**: i need to show label while typing and after selected because i need to store multiple input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

```
var itemLabel = arr[i].label,
    itemValue = arr[i].value;
```

Use one of these wherever you are using `arr[i]` directly. I am searching user-entered input on `label` but you can add on `value`, if needed.

You can check this fiddle for further details: https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pg2dsj3u/1/

Hope this helps. Please let me know in the comments if you have any doubts.

**Edit**

Just for reference, you can check `select2.js`. It provides auto-complete feature with many other features on select-boxes. [Here is the link](https://select2.org/).

**Edit Reference**
https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pg2dsj3u/

Comment: one small change, after selecting option i need label to display in input field, and value should be passed to hidden field.

Comment: @sanojlawrence https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pg2dsj3u/9 -> Please check this out. hope it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: that's a great work but what i was asking is `how do i pass value to hidden input field`

Comment: basically 2 input field one with selected label, and another with value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pg2dsj3u/ -> Have achieved both here
The visible input will have label and the hidden one will have value

Comment: i want hidden input to be in `html` please check my question, i need to pass value to that hidden field

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want 2 input fields in the HTML after deleting an input: 1 with label and another with the selected value?

Comment: yes 2 inputs, one with label and another input with value.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest, setting a `data-attribute` on the same input instead of adding a new hidden input to the DOM. kind of like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pg2dsj3u/

Comment: is there any other way to get in separate input, because i need to inputs

Comment: because i need two inputs, if we use `data-attribute` how do i pass value to form,

Comment: There is a way as in you can already add a hidden input below *myInput*. And then keep changing its value.

Comment: `<input id="myInput" type="text" name="Input-lable" placeholder="Country">
 <input type="hidden" name="input_value">` how do i do that.

Comment: lets make it simple when i select a option `label` should pass to `<input id="myInput" type="text" name="Input-lable" placeholder="Country">` and value should pass to `<input type="hidden" name="input_value">`

Answer (score -1):

You can use datalist HTML to do this tag.

```
<input id="myInput" list="" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">

<datalist id="countries">
  <option value="Afghanistan">
  <option value="Albania">
  <option value="Algeria">
</datalist>
```

In option tag, you can add all your countries list.

Comment: Have you read the question, i mentioned i need to add multiple value with label.